# What is Dutch's relationship to Boomer?

Tags: far-cry-5

After playing Far Cry 5 for a little while, I traveled back to Dutch's bunker and next to the fish tank, I found a picture of Boomer:

[image: Screenshot of the picture of boomer next to the fish tank.]

Since:

> Boomer is rescued from Rae Rae's pumpkin farm.

What is Dutch's relationship to Boomer?

Answer (score 4):

Boomer was originally owned by Rae Rae. He got taken by Project at Eden's Gate and was in their compound for a while. If you free him during the game, you can recruit him as a companion.

If you play the entire game, after you free him, you'll notice they get very attached. He sleeps in his bed, and they have a pretty deep attachment. You'll even see him petting and playing with him sometimes.

There's more to it, but I can't go into those details without spoiling Far Cry New Dawn.

But to answer your question in the short version, they are extremely close.